# FullCalendar date offset from Office365

Tags: javascript, php, fullcalendar, office365, outlook-restapi

I am importing events from Office365 into FullCalendar to display on a website, but the time displayed has 1 hour offset from the time set for the events on Office365 (i.e events set to 14:00:00 are being shown as 13:00:00), and I'm stuck and can't figure out why that is happening.

The function creating the events for the calendar:

```
    function getTentativeEvents(){

    client

        .api("/me/calendars/"+calID1+"/calendarview/?$top=3000&$filter=ShowAs eq 'Tentative'&startDateTime="+calStartDate+"&endDateTime="+calEndDate)

        .select("Subject,Start,Id,End,Categories")

        .get((err, res) => {

            if (err) {

                console.log(err);

                return;

            }

            console.log(res);

            var catNameFound = "";

            var categoryTitleTotal = timeSlotsCategoryTitleArray.length;

            var arrayLength = res['value'].length;

            var counter = arrayLength -1;

            for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {

                var eveColour = defaultTimeSlotBackgroundColour;

                var eveTxtColour = defaultTimeSlotTextColour;

                var categoriesLength = res['value'][i]['categories'].length;

                if(categoriesLength >= 1){

                    for (var i2 = 0; i2 < categoriesLength; i2++) {

                        var catNameFound = res['value'][i]['categories'][i2];

                        catNameFound = catNameFound.toLowerCase();

                        for (var i3 = 0; i3 < categoryTitleTotal; i3++) {

                            var timeSlotToCheck = timeSlotsCategoryTitleArray[i3];

                            timeSlotToCheck = timeSlotToCheck.toLowerCase();

                            //console.log(catNameFound);

                            if(timeSlotToCheck == catNameFound){

                                eveColour = timeSlotsBackgroundColourArray[i3];

                                eveTxtColour = timeSlotsTextColourArray[i3];

                            }

                        }

                    }

                }

                eventSubject = res['value'][i]['subject'];

                eventID = res['value'][i]['id']; 

                startDate = res['value'][i]['start']['dateTime'];

                endDate = res['value'][i]['end']['dateTime'];

                startDate = startDate.replace(".0000000", "");

                endDate = endDate.replace(".0000000", "");

                addToEventList(eventSubject,startDate,endDate,eventID,eveColour,eveTxtColour);          

            }

            //

            $('#calendar1').fullCalendar('gotoDate', '<?php echo $theDateAfter; ?>');

            $("#calendar1").fullCalendar('addEventSource', timeSlotsArray);

            $('#calendarLoader').hide();

            $('#calendar1').show();

    });
```

And the parameters for the calendar:

```
header: {

        left: 'prev,next today',

        center: 'title',

        right: ''

},

    defaultView: 'agendaDay',

    defaultDate: '<?php echo $theDateAfter; ?>',

    eventColor: defaultTimeSlotBackgroundColour,

    minTime: "10:00:00",

    timezone: "Europe/London",

    ignoreTimezone: false,

    maxTime: "20:00:00",

    editable: false
```

I checked the settings on Office365 and it is set correctly to UTC +0 (London).

What am I missing?

Comment: what do the start/end times in the actual import data look like? Have they got the timezone specified?

Comment: They come like this: 2017-05-26T12:00:00.0000000, I am trimming the extra zeros as you can see on the code.

Comment: could it be related to the fact it's summer time right now in Britain so the clocks are one hour ahead of UTC. https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converted.html?iso=20130911T160009&p1=0&p2=136 Office365 might be showing the BST time? Check the exported data vs what's actually shown on screen in Office, and also those dates don't have any timezone specified which could be muddling things up.

Comment: Yes, it could be that, but considering that both Office365 and FullCalendar are set to the correct timezone, it makes no sense, unless the the Office365 API is ignoring the timezone and exporting in UTC? Doing some digging around I found out that I can specify the timezone when requesting the events from office365 with 'Prefer: outlook.timezone="Europe/London"', but this is an HTTP header request, I don't know to implement this within the javascript.

Comment: you seem to be using some library i'm not familiar with to make the api request, but in general terms it's certainly possible to set http headers for ajax requests. maybe look at the library's documentation for how you might do so. here https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timezone/timezone/ it says if you specify a fullcalendar timezone, then "Your server-side script is then expected to use the timezone parameter to calculate the timezone offset of the returned ISO8601 dates!"

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using the REST API to connect to Office365, but the documentation doesn't tell how to do it...

Comment: is it a JS library that Microsoft supplied? What's the link to it please? Maybe I can look at it and see if I can work it out.

Comment: It is not a JS library, but you can see the reference here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations

Comment: so then what is enabling you to write `client

        .api("/me/calendars/"+calID1+"/calendarview/?$top=3000&$filter=ShowAs eq 'Tentative'&startDateTime="+calStartDate+"&endDateTime="+calEndDate)

        .select("Subject,Start,Id,End,Categories")` etc? It's not standard JS, or jQuery ajax, or anything else that I recognise. Whatever that code is, that's where you need to be able to understand how to set headers. I assume it's some 3rd-party library, unless it's a home-made thing?

Comment: It is Microsoft Graph, and it was done by someone else, i'm just trying to unpick it.... The variable `client` is defined as: `var client = MicrosoftGraph.init({
  debugLogging: true,
  authProvider: function(done) {
   done(null, "<?php echo $cal365_authentication_token; ?>");
  }
 });`

Comment: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript#header-and-headers shows you how to add headers to a request

Comment: Thanks, that looks like what I need, but I am struggling with the syntax. I tried `.header("Prefer: outlook.timezone", "Europe/London")` but it causes an 'invalid header name' error, and `.header("outlook.timezone", "Europe/London")` doesn't change anything.

Comment: did you check in the browser' network tab each time whether it creates the header as you'd expect within the API request? I haven't really got any information than what's in those two bits of documentation.

Answer (score 1):

It is happening because the times are returned in UTC. You need to convert them to your local time. There is a very good library called [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/). You can use the following code using that library:

```
var localTime  = moment.utc(startDate).toDate();
    localTime = moment(localTime).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
```